# How to set bool value to true in mvc entityframework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Briefly

I'm creating a social site in MVC5.....
I've a model User where i have some of these properties fname,lname,username,email,isNew...etc

so i've set isNew to false and when i press Login Button i've a if condition:

if(isNew==true) than redirect...to Index(A.M) Home(C) ....

else redirect....to NewUser(A.M) Steps(C)...

Now when i clicked Login Button its works pretty good i mean it redirect me to Steps(Controller) NewUser(ActionMethod) now here i want to set isNew value to true but i've no idea how to do this

This is what i have tried...

```
public ActionResult NewUser(User model)
    {
        using (DbAccess db=new DbAccess())
        {

            var original=db.users.Find(model.uid);
            original.isNew = true;
              //var entry = db.Entry(original);
              //entry.Property(e => e.isNew).IsModified = true;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return Content("Welcome");
    }
```

i'm new to Mvc/EntityFramework/Linq so no idea how to update this bool value...

Comment: What exactly is the problem ?

Comment: What makes you think `isNew` isn't updated?

Comment: the problem is isNew value not changing in database...

Comment: help me please...........

Answer (score 0):

yes i find out the solution...

```
var user=db.users.Where(m => m.isNew == false).FirstOrDefault();
user.isNew = true;
```